# Clear TextBox when ComboBox Selection is Changed

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Below is my `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Text="Hello" />
```

and  my `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="srchType" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="srchType_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Question" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value" />
</ComboBox>
```

Now I can clear the text from TextBox using code behind. like below

```
private void srchType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    asb.Text = "";
}
```

But i want to do this in `xaml` rather than using CodeBehind because I have few comboboxes and every selection change event has to do certain action. (Simple actions but they are not same as clearing textboxes ).

Can anyone point me to how this can be achieved in `xaml`. Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very close to what Andrii posted, but there are some differences in UWP.

First of all, the Behaviors SDK is not built-in UWP, but has to be downloaded separately from NuGet.

You can use the following command to install it:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```

Or just use the NuGet Package Manager and search for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.

After you install, you can just add the XAML using statements to the top of your page:

```xml
<Page ...
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" />
```

And use the `ChangePropertyAction` to change the value when needed. In UWP XAML you can actually normally use the empty string as value and it works as expected.

```xml
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="srchType" SelectedIndex="0">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction 
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TheTextBoxToUpdate}"
                PropertyName="Text" Value=""  />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Question" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Oh, I tested my code on Windows Phone 8.1, and `Value="` didn't work, so I created `EmptyString`

Comment: @MZetko, This is exactly what i need. I went through Interaction.Behaviors documentation and I can see it can do lot of stuff. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Cool, I didn't know it didn't work there :-) !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XAML Behaviors`:

Declare required namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

and use it

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox"
                Text="Hello"/>

    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <i:BehaviorCollection>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text"
                                                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox}"
                                                Value="{Binding Empty, Source={StaticResource EmptyString}}">
                    </core:ChangePropertyAction>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:BehaviorCollection>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
        <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
        <x:Int32>3</x:Int32>
        <x:Int32>4</x:Int32>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

But, you can see

```
Value="{Binding Empty, Source={StaticResource EmptyString}}"
```

By default, you can't declare empty string in XAML (maybe in UWP something changed), so I created helper class for it:

```
public class EmptyString : DependencyObject
{
    public string Empty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EmptyProperty); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Empty", typeof(string), typeof(EmptyString), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

and declare on page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:EmptyString x:Name="EmptyString"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: While this worked for me, I was able to bind my controls without creating a dependancy object in code behind. So you get a bonus. Thanks.